# Check multiple Unique columns when using POST method(RestAPI)

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework

Pretend that I have multiple unique columns in my database.

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

When I use POST method, I will use 4 queries to check each of these field exist in database.(If not then I will POST them in database)

I am wondering is there a smarter way to check all multiple unique in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a query that matches any existing records where any of the fields match using `OR` via [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects. `Q` objects can be used to create `OR` filters by chaining them with the `|` operator

```
fields_are_not_unique = YourModel.objects.filter(
    Q(username=form.cleaned_data['username'])
    | Q(email=form.cleaned_data['email'])
    | Q(phone_number=form.cleaned_data['phone_number'])
    | Q(serial_number=form.cleaned_data['serial_number'])
).exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

Might the [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method help you here?